# Why the events with custom accessors cannot be fired directly as the default ones do?

Tags: c#, events

If I write something like the code below,

```
class MainClass
{
    static EventHandler _myEvent= delegate{};
    static event EventHandler MyEvent
    {
        add{_myEvent += value;}
        remove{_myEvent -= value;}
    }

    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        MyEvent(null,EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

the compiler will complain: Error CS0079: The event `MainClass.MyEvent' can only appear on the left hand side of`+=' or `-=' operator .

Why does something as weird as this exist at all? If I can't fire an event directly, why would I use such a thing in the first place? Is that a bug(I'm using mono) or deliberate delicate design? Could anyone please teach me the rationale behind this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can only access an event in the declaring class.  Behind the scenes, .NET creates private instance variables to hold the delegate.

The compiler is actually creating a public event, and a private field.  You can access the field directly from the same class or nested classes.  From external classes, you would only be allowed to subscribe/unsubscribe.

Great information from Jon Skeet is available [here](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter2/Events.aspx) on as to why this is and how it works.

Comment: That's not the issue here. The attempt to access the event _is_ from within the declaring class...

Comment: @Nick: No, this is absolutely saying what's going on: for a field-like event a call which appears to be invoking the event is actually invoking via the field. You then take that knowledge and apply it to the custom event - invoking *that* via the backing field too.

Comment: @Jon: I agree that you can work backwards from how field-like events are implemented to understand error CS0079. Had the answer concentrated on that, it would have been +1 and done from me. However, the answer focuses on the field's private accessibility, and that is beside the point.

Comment: @Jon: It's part of every sentence but the last, but hey... ;)

Answer (score 2):

You need to invoke your manually declared backing delegate to raise the event: replace `MyEvent(null, EventArgs.Empty)` with `_myEvent(null, EventArgs.Empty)`. If you think about it, the custom add/remove could be storing the delegates anywhere, which is why you can't retrieve and invoke them the way you've written it...

Comment: :But, what if I wanna derive the class and I don't wanna expose the underlying delegate field to the subclass? That will be a mess, won't it?  I just observed that subclasses are not allowed to fire the events of their base class.Isn't this design kinda weak? Events are employed to prevent the outsiders to mess with it. But why the insiders are also restricted?

Comment: The recommended pattern is to provide a protected virtual method that raises the event: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229011.aspx.

Comment: Thanks for you link. However, I still think the not-allow-to-fire design is pretty lame. The events can be virtual and be overridden by subclasses, but to fire them, we have to resort to some helper virtual methods, how is that not lame?